# Creating a connection to Vertica database in python using adodbapi

Tags: python, connection-string, ironpython, vertica, adodbapi

Does anyone know what are the parameters for creating a connection string to Vertica database using adodbapi? I cannot use pyodbc, because it does not work with IronPython.

I have tried:

```
    connectorsver = ["DRIVER=Vertica ODBC Driver 4.1"]
    connectorsver.append("SERVER=1.1.1.1\xx")
    connectorsver.append ("DATABASE=mydatabase")
    connectorsver.append ("User Id=dbadmin")
    connectorsver.append ("Password=xxx")
            con = adodbapi.connect(";".join (connectorsver))
```

and that returned an operational error. The same technique with an MSSQL connection string worked fine. When I created a DSN in Windows with this information, it also made a successful connection to vertica.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Unit Tests for ADODBAPO](http://adodbapi.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/adodbapi/adodbapi/file/446fe3e47c67/test/testADOdbapi.py#l435), `connect()` will `raise` an `adodbapi.DatabaseError` on failure. You should check for this exception:

```
try:
    con = adodbapi.connect(";".join (connectorsver))
except adodbapi.DatabaseError, e:
    print e
```

Watch your indentation, too. It looks like you're mixing tabs and spaces. Python's very sensitive to such things.

I've not used Vertica, but you may find answers to [does anyone know the format of an odbc connection string for vertica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807510/does-anyone-know-the-format-of-an-odbc-connection-string-for-vertica) to be of interest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks #Johnsyweb. The printed exception was much more detailed and that has helped me find and fix the issue.

Comment: @downvoter: Why? This answer clearly solved the OP's problem.