# Connection to Vertica via VBA

Tags: vba, vertica

I'm trying to connect to Vertica via VBA code.  But I'm facing this error:

```
 Run Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
 Automation error
 Unspecified error
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim strConn As String
strConn = "Driver={Vertica}; Servername=localhost; 
Database=jdbc:vertica://JSVERTICA:5433/PVXDW; Username=admin; Password=pass"

cn.Open strConn
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
MsgBox "Connected"
```

Comment: What line causes that error?

Comment: cn.Open strConn

Comment: Follow these steps: [Testing an ODBC DSN Using Excel](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientODBC/TestingADSNUsingExcel.htm)

Comment: This might help too: [Creating an ODBC DSN for Windows Clients](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/InstallingDrivers/Windows/CreatingAnODBCDSNForWindowsClients.htm?tocpath=Connecting%20to%20Vertica%7CClient%20Libraries%7CCreating%20an%20ODBC%20Data%20Source%20Name%20(DSN)%7CCreating%20an%20ODBC%20DSN%20for%20Windows%20Clients%7C_____0)

Comment: Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5807510/5162073) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change strConn value as below and try to connect the database.

```
strConn = "Provider=VerticaOLEDB.1;Data Source=JSVERTICA;Initial Catalog=PVXDW;User ID=admin;Password=pass;"
```